# wxPython - DatePickerCtrl seems to ignore SetValue()

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to pre-populate a wxPython DatePicker with a value using the following code:

```
month, day, year = runData[2][0:8].split('/')
displayDate = wx.DateTimeFromDMY(int(day), int(month) - 1, int(year))
self.datePicker.SetValue(displayDate)
```

Here are the printed values:

- runData[2] = 12/16/09 00:00
- month, day, year = 12 16 09
- displayDate = 12/16/09 00:00:00

But, datePicker always shows today's date instead.

Any ideas?

I'm using Python 2.6.4 with wxPython 2.8.10.1 on Windows 7.

Thanks.

---

Update 20/12/09 16:30:

When I try and process the information from the DatePickerCtrl with the problem, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1120, in onOk
    dateLong = self.datePicker.GetValue()
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_controls.py", line
6465, in GetValue
    return _controls_.DatePickerCtrlBase_GetValue(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "m_date.IsValid() == dt.IsValid() && (!
dt.IsValid() || dt == m_date)" failed at ..\..\src\msw\datectrl.cpp(278) in wxDa
tePickerCtrl::GetValue(): bug in wxDatePickerCtrl: m_date not in sync
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Platform? Windows? Linux? Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making year 2009 instead of 9?

Comment: The background seems to be that dates before 1700 are not accepted by wx.DateTime. If you pass 01-01-1500, the control will show today instead.